# Will merge be available in libgit2sharp?

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

There are merge functions in libgit2. But I can't find merge funciton in libgit2. Is there any schedule to wrap the implementation in libgit2sharp?

Comment: You should go to github issues to ask this question. https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues

Comment: This kind of question is precisely what shouldn't be made into an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge isn't available in LibGit2Sharp. Yet.

Indeed, Merge is still a work in progress in libgit2. This feature is mainly lead by **[@ethomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson)**.

Some lower level features have already been merged in libgit2, though (cf. [#1592](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1592), [#1389](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1389), [#1185](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1185), [#1011](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1011) and some other minor ones).

Some of those bits have already been made available to LibGit2Sharp (see [MergeFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/MergeFixture.cs), [CommitFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/1d4d35ab4dc01b17f77c4c25e5a3faa0415b0e86/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CommitFixture.cs#L547-L611), [ConflictFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/1465bf31cdfcf59bceab42bb0e8d0543b02503dc/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/ConflictFixture.cs), [CheckoutFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/1d4d35ab4dc01b17f77c4c25e5a3faa0415b0e86/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CheckoutFixture.cs#L226-L310)).

The main PR to follow is [#1007](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/1007). I'd suggest you to subscribe to it in order to be notified about it. Once it's merged, the feature will be made available in LibGit2Sharp.

### Update

Merge is happening! See **[Pull request #608](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/608)** for further details.

Comment: Looks like #1007 has been deleted. #65 seems to be tracking something similar, however. https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/65

Comment: @ChrisMoschini I fixed the link to #1007.